# Помогите разобраться с задачей на python с сайта Checkio

Tags: python

> Дан словарь, в котором в качестве ключей используются строки, а в
>   качестве значений строки или словари. Необходимо сделать этот словарь
>   “плоским”, но сохранить структуру в ключах.
>
> Результатом будет словарь без вложенных словарей. Ключи должны
>   содержать путь, составленный из родительских ключей из начального
>   словаря, разделенных `/`. Если значение ключа есть пустой словарь,
>   тогда оно должно быть заменено пустой строкой (`""`).

Никак не пойму как изменить этот код:

```
def flatten(dictionary):
    stack = 
    result = {}
    while stack:
        path, current = stack.pop()
        for k, v in current.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append((path + (k,), v))
            else:
                result = v
    return result
```

Ввод:

```
print (flatten({"key": {"deeper": {"more": {}}}}))
```

Вывод : `{}`
А должен быть : `{"key/deeper/more": ""}`

Comment: Что скрывается в переменной `stack`?

Comment: @m9_psy    stack = [((), dictionary)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def flatten(dt: dict):
    for k in dt:
        yield k
        dk = dt[k]
        if isinstance(dk, dict):
            if dk: yield from flatten(dk)
            else: yield ""
        else: yield dk

dts = {"key": {"deeper": {"more": {}}},
       "key2": {"deeper2": {"more2": '123'}}}
for k in dts:
    b = list(flatten({k: dts[k]}))
    print({'/'.join(b[:-1]): b[-1]})
```

OUT:

```
{'key/deeper/more': ''}
{'key2/deeper2/more2': '123'}
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
def flatten(dictionary):
    stack = list(dictionary.items())
    result = {}
    while stack:
        path, current = stack.pop()
        if current == {}:
            result[path] = ""
        for k, v in current.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append(("/".join([path, k]), v))
            else:
                result["/".join([path, k])] = v
    return result
```

Исходные данные вопроса:

```
print (flatten({"key": {"deeper": {"more": {}}}}))

{'key/deeper/more': ''}
```

Более сложная структура:

```
print (flatten({"key": {"deeper": {"more": {}}, "deep2": "more2"}, "key2": {"deep3":"more3"}}))

{'key2/deep3': 'more3', 'key/deeper/more': '', 'key/deep2': 'more2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я, когда решал эту задачу на checkio, сделал это так:

```
def flatten(dictionary):
    stack = [((), dictionary)]
    result = {}
    while stack:
        path, current = stack.pop()
        for k, v in current.items():
            if v == {}: v = ''
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append((path + (k,), v))
            else:
                result["/".join((path + (k,)))] = v
    return result
```

Comment: Ну тогда Отметьте, ответ который вам больше понравился, а ещё можно проголосовать (треугольничек смотрит вверх) ;)